# Trident doing incorrect aggregations on Kafka stream

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-storm, trident

I am new to Storm trident. Here is my problem:

I am consuming messages from Kafka queue and using an implementation of `CombinerAggregator` to do the aggregation, to persist the data in Cassandra.

When I run this thing locally, I am seeing numbers getting populated correctly. But on production environment, I am seeing most of the times these aggregations are coming as 0, which is wrong, we should have values for these cases as well. And in some cases non-zero numbers are appearing which are correct.

I have set `numOfWorkers` for my topology as 4 and `parallelismHint` as 2. Would you know what can go wrong? Or suggest a way to debug this problem.

Comment: Can you provide your code? And maybe an data snippet as example?

Comment: Figured out, there was an incorrect mapping in the topology. Fixed it.